Oracle DatabaseChangeNotification in a multiple cluster environment
Oracle DatabaseChangeNotification gets broadcast to the application ( with listeners) in multiple cluster environment. I want it should be sent to only one Listener. If that listerner goes down then only event get notify to others.
Want to implement Oracle DatabaseChangeNotification in a multiple cluster environment . But what we desire is that the data change notification should be sent to only one instance of the application , because as of now it sending the change notification to all of the instance. How do I get the desired characteristic?
Listener code :
    DCNDemoListener list = new DCNDemoListener(this); dcr.addListener(list);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ((OracleStatement)stmt).setDatabaseChangeRegistration(dcr);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from employee");

Properties :
OracleConnection conn = connect();
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_NOTIFY_ROWIDS,"true");
prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_QUERY_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION,"true");
DatabaseChangeRegistration dcr = conn.registerDatabaseChangeNotification(prop);

